# Is it possible to "brute combine" sections of bitmaps in R (perhaps by incorporating e.g. Python code, if needed)?

Tags: python, r, ggplot2, ggsave

This question is an expansion of [an earlier discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77076487/how-do-i-add-a-legend-indicating-significance-levels-below-a-ggplot-object/77077095#77077095), where a good solution is described, but a more brutal combining method might be necessary in some scenarios.

Consider the following MWEs that produce the two bitmaps.

First, graph 1:

```r
# Load packages
library(ggforestplot)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
# Use the example data of the ggforesplot() package (only a few rows of it)
df <- ggforestplot::df_linear_associations %>%
  filter(trait == "BMI") %>% slice(26:27)
# Create plot
ggforestplot::forestplot(
  df = df,
  name = name,
  estimate = beta,
  se = se,
  pvalue = pvalue,
  psignif = 0.05
)
# Export as png
ggsave("graph1.png", width = 8, bg = 'white', dpi = 150)
```

[image]

Graph 2:

```r
# Load packages
library(ggstats)
# Load example data
data(tips, package = "reshape")
# Run linear model
linear_model <- lm(tip ~ size + total_bill, data = tips)
# Plot model
ggcoef_model(linear_model)
# Export as png
ggsave("graph2.png", width = 8, bg = 'white', dpi = 150)
```

[image]

Let's say I want to cut a slice (here: a legend) with the height of 79 pixels (ca 10.8%) from the bottom of the 2nd graph (second bitmap file) and append that to the 1st graph (1st bitmap file).

Is there a way to do this straight in R, or alternatively, by incorporating Python code into an R script?

The result I desire is shown below:

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the `magick` package

Comment: Alternative: use the `patchwork` package to combine a plot of just the legend (which would take a little finagling to create).

Comment: `magick` looks great for this purpose, I'll have a look. `patchwork` could do, but it seems that `patchwork` is not for brute combining bitmaps but rather a bit like `gridExtra::grid.arrange()` and `cowplot::plot_grid()`.